# php/sql - insert same value on multiple field

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code (this is working and pass these variable to another file)

```
            var month = "<?php echo openedMonthbid();?>";
    var user = "<?php echo $_SESSION['member_id'];?>";
    var day = new Array();


    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
    day.push('`' + $(this).val() + '`');  });
    var count = day.length;

                            $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "sendBidding.php",
                            data : "user="+user+"&days="+day+"&month="+month+"&number=",
                            dataType: "json",
```

sendBidding.php

```
$month = $_POST['month'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$days = $_POST['days'];
$count = $_POST['count'];//if a check 3 values I get '3'


      mysql_query("INSERT INTO $month ($days) VALUES ('1','1','1')");


    $result = true;

    echo json_encode(array("success"=>$result,
                               "datas" => $data,
                                "mon"=>$month));
```

I would like to add as many values ('1') as the number of days selected. How can I change VALUES ('1','1','1') ?

Comment: Your code completely lacks proper escaping of SQL. It is dangerous, because you are using the data from $_POST not as a value (which can be escaped with `mysql_real_escape_string()`), but as the names for tables and columns, for which no pre-made escaping function is available. Prepared statements would fail here, too. Go a different route!

Comment: @Sven you are absolutely right. I will make those changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution for generating a sequence of identical strings.  Use [`array_fill()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php).

```
$month = $_POST['month'];
$days = $_POST['days'];

// Be sure to whitelist $month and $days before using them in an SQL query!  
// For example, you could store an associative array keyed by month,
// containing lists of the day column names.
$month_table_whitelist = array(
  "month_jan" => array("day1", "day2", "day3", /* etc */),
  "month_feb" => array("day1", "day2", "day3", /* etc */),
  /* etc */
);
if (!array_key_exists($month, $month_table_whitelist)) {
  die("Please specify a valid month.");
}
if (!array_search($days, $month_table_whitelist[$month])) {
  die("Please specify a valid day of month.");
}

$count = $_POST['count'];//if a check 3 values I get '3'

$tuples = array_fill(1, $count, "('1')");

$status = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $month ($days) VALUES ".implode(",", $tuples));
if ($status === false) {
  die(mysql_error());
}
```

PS:  Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection, by interpolating unsafe values $month and $days directly into your query.  You should use a whitelist method to ensure these inputs match real table and column names in your database, don't just trust the user input.

PPS: You should know that you're using the ext/mysql functions, but these are deprecated.  If this is a new application, you should start using mysqli or PDO before investing more time into using the deprecated API.

Comment: I know, i'm still learling and I've been lazy. I will start to change  that tomorrow. Ps I tried your code but when I check the database, there is no record.

Comment: So it failed silently, but we'll never know the cause unless we check for an error return status from the mysql_query() function.  I have added that to the code above.

Comment: Escaping or sanitization for $month and $days is missing. This code is open for SQL injection.

Comment: @Sven, yes, I had addressed that issue with a comment, but I did not show an implementation of a whitelist.  I have edited the above with an example.  Please reverse your downvote.

Comment: @BillKarwin I think I found the error. if I leave $tuples = array_fill(1, $count, "('1')") the query doesn't work  but if I change $count with a number (like 3) it does work. Is it possible that $count is just the string 3 and not the number 3 and that's why array_fill() doesn't work?

Comment: @mattia, PHP will automatically convert a string with digits into an integer in most cases.  Another possibility is that $_POST["count"] isn't set.

Comment: @BillKarwin that was the problem Bill, $_POST["count"] wan't set. I also changed your code. Now it works perfectly! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
$count = $_POST['count'];//if a check 3 values I get '3'

$daystatic="('1')";

mysql_query("INSERT INTO $month ($days) VALUES ". $daystatic . str_repeat ( ",$daystatic" , $count-1));
```

Comment: Escaping or sanitization for $month and $days is missing. This code is open for SQL injection.